# QGIS 3.0.3 takes a lot of time to save selected features

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm editing a large .xml layer with over million points and 2GB of data.

I'm trying to save selected features (about 100 000 points).

After an hour of saving, I have just 77 kb of data saved. With this pace, it'd take weeks to have a full file.

Any idea why it takes so long?

Comment: Did you try to save to different file formats? Did you try with newer QGIS versions as well?

Comment: Yes, I've tried .shp, .gml, .geojson and everything's slow, but I didn't try newer releases.

Comment: Are you able to "work" with the data? I can't imagine an xml file of 2GB size can be used effectively (unless there is some sort of spatial index involved somewhere)

Comment: I'm able to select data by expression. It's slow, but not to the point of extreme.

Comment: However, it may be possible that it's just too big for QGIS, but I thought that saving should be little faster if QGIS was able to do a selection.

Comment: The only explanation I can see is, that it would internally do a lookup and full scan for each feature id. This takes a lot of time with a plain xml without indexes. It might be possible to speedup things by saving the full data to an intermediate file (e.g. gpkg) and then select / save as from there.

Comment: PyQGIS may help.